# Pass individual elements to zero rank in fortran + mpi

Tags: arrays, fortran, mpi

I try to parallel my fortran program by means of mpi. The point is that I have to pass some individual elements (not all) of an array from some rank to zero rank. Namely, it is needed to pass every, say, 4th element. Is there some possibility to implement such passing process using group communication procedures? Thank you in advance for any response.

Comment: yes, use a derived datatype.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet thank you for the response! Does these derived data types work in fortran90?

Comment: yes, they work in all languages.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I'll try it, Thank you so much!